# Calculate the sums of products of all natural solutions to $x_1+...+x_k=n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider all the Natural pairs $(x_1,...,x_k)$ such that $x_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x_k=n$. ($k<n$)

Calculate the two following sums:
$$
\sum_{(x_1,...,x_k)|x_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x_k=n}x_1\cdot\cdot\cdot x_k
$$
$$
\sum_{(x_1,...,x_k)|x_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x_k=n}{n\choose x_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot{n\choose x_k}
$$

Comment: Let above sum $s_n,k$. There is one nice recursive property there, $s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n is_{n-i,k-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: look for the coefficient in front of $y^n$ in $(y/(1-y)^2)^k$ and in $((1+y)^n)^k$ (use binomial formula in both cases)

more detail: expand $y/(1-y)^2$ (to a power series - for problem 1) and $(1+y)^n$ (problem 2) - just use the binomial formula. See what happens with this expansion when you raise it to the $k$-th power - your answer will appear as the coefficient in front of $y^n$. You can expand those $k$-th powers directly, again using binomial formula. Perhaps start with problem 2, which only uses polynomials and no power series.

Comment: please add more detail :)

Comment: In problem 2 you count actually the sum for natural plus _zero_ solutions ($x_i=0$).

Comment: for me $0$ is a natural number (as for 50% of people) - you should be more precise in your question.